# Query Regarding the below code snippet

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String s1="abc";
        String s2="xyz";
        String s3="abcxyz";

        String s4=s1.concat(s2);
        System.out.println(s4);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String s5=s1+s2;

        if(s3==s4)
        {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("false");
    }
```

Why the o/p is coming as false? According to me it should be true. Can someone please explain

Comment: == checks for reference,if you want to check for data then use .equals()

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen link answer for you

Answer (score -1):

**java.lang.String concat() function return new String() object** Here `s3 and s4` are two different references pointing to two different objects.

`==` just checks for refernces wheras `.equals()` checks for the actual content.

> ```
> s3.equals(s4) will return true.
> ```

From javadoc, concat() function.

```
 public String concat(String str) {
        int otherLen = str.length();
        if (otherLen == 0) {
            return this;
        }
        int len = value.length;
        char buf[] = Arrays.copyOf(value, len + otherLen);
        str.getChars(buf, len);
        return new String(buf, true);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`==` operator compares `String` value as well as `String` memory location. Here, `s3` and `s4` are using different memory locations.

If you want to compare values of `String` then you should use `s3.equals(s4)`. It will result into true condition.